# Too much space after integral sign with unicode-math and lualatex

Tags: math-mode, spacing, luatex, unicode-math

(I had a feeling this was a duplicate, but couldn't find an older question about it. Forgive me if I'm just bad at searching.)

Consider the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `lualatex` the space between the integral sign and `f(x)` is too large, larger than what I get if I compile with `xelatex` (or if I'm not using `unicode-math`).

- With `lualatex`:

[image]

- With `xelatex`:

[image]

- Without `unicode-math`:

[image]

I'm using a recently updated TeXlive 2011, and the same thing happens with `Asana-Math.otf` or `xits-math.otf` as math font. Can this be corrected somehow?

Comment: Happens the same to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 28-10-2015**: This has been fixed in version 0.85 of LuaTeX, see http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=488

---

Looks something wrong with italic correction of integrals in the absence of super or subscripts, adding an empty superscript `\int^{} f(x)` fixes the spacing. Odd enough, adding empty subscript `\int_{} f(x)` makes it even closer! I'd report this to luatex bug tracker.

Comment: After tracking down the bug tracker, it seems you've reported this already, about a year ago: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=488

Comment: Or, that issue doesn't say anything about `unicode-math`, so it is somewhat different. Should I make a new issue, or just add a comment to that one?

Comment: I think it is the same issue, I totally forgot about it :)

Comment: In TL2012, this issue has disappeared in ConTeXt, but still exists in `unicode-math`. Maybe `unicode-math` needs to be updated? Or the newest ConTeXt contains this hack you mentioned to get around the engine bug?

Comment: @C.R.: most likely ConTeXt has a workaround for it.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Is it possible to implement a workaround in LaTeX?

Comment: @C.R.: I don’t know what the work around is…

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is still in TL2014. Is it going to be fixed anytime soon?

Comment: @KhaledHosny, it also happens in TL2015. Sorry to say it, but it makes `unicode-math` pretty much useless for serious production work. Has no workaround been found yet?

Comment: This, along with the incorrect positioning of sub-/superscripts for integral signs (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267062/51235, which is supposedly the same bug), really destroys any use `unicode-math` might have offered. Why is this issue being ignored?

Comment: @Socob, it seems the bug fix is here at last. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler Finally :-)

I just hope it actually fixes all the problems...

Comment: Any ideas when this will make its way to TeX Live?

Comment: It is on TeX live now, and the spacing is fixed, but the subscripts look quite far from the integral sign. A new bug perhaps?