# Bad `\limits` spacing with lualatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math, latin-modern

Compiling this example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \int\limits_a^b x² \,\symup{d}x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex` looks a lot uglier than compiling with `xelatex`.
The spacing of the `\limits` is just way out of perfect:

#### lualatex result:

[image: lualatex]

#### xelatex result:

[image]

Comment: That's a know bug with LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Without an available fix?

Comment: Not that I know, except manual back up. I'll try later.

Comment: I asked the same thing several years back: [Too much space after integral sign with unicode-math and lualatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36699)

Comment: note also the position of the sub/superscripts

Comment: @egreg The other question does not mention the wrongly positioned sub/superscripts

Comment: @MaxNoe It's the same bug.

Comment: This was fixed in v0.85 of LuaTeX: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=488

Comment: A shame that there are no binary updates in TL even if there are severe improvements